# Use IIS Rewrite Module to redirect to Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

My MVC project uses the default location (/Content/...)

So where this code:

```
<div id="header"style="background-image: url('/Content/images/header_.jpg')">
```

resolves as  **www.myDomain.com/content/images/header_.jpg**

I'm moving my images files to S3 so now they resolve from 'http://images.myDomain.com' Do I have to convert all the links in the project to that absolute path?

Is there perhaps an IIS7x property to help here?

EDIT: The question seems to boil down to the specifics of working with IIS's Rewrite Module. The samples I've seen so far show how to manipulate the lower ends and query string of a URI. I'm needing to remap the domain end of the URI:

http://www.myDomain.com/content/images/header_.jpg
needs to become:
   http://images.myDomain.com/header_.jpg

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly.  Do you mean

> How do I transparently rewrite image urls like http://www.myDomain.com/Content/myImage.png as http://images.myDomain.com/Content/myImage.png at render time?

Or

> How do I serve images like http://images.myDomain.com/Content/myImage.png transparently from S3?

There's a DNS trick to answer the second one.

Create the 'images.myDomain.com' bucket, and put your content in it under the '/Content/' path.  Since S3 exposes buckets as domains in their own right, you can now get your content with

http://images.myDomain.com.s3.amazonaws.com/Content/myImage.png

You can then create a CNAME record in your own DNS provider taking 'images.myDomain.com' to 'images.myDomain.com.s3.amazonaws.com'

This lets you link to your images as

http://images.myDomain.com/Content/myImage.png

..and yet have them served from S3 (You might also consider a full CDN such as cloud front.)

Comment: I think i'm looking for a combination of your two alternatives. I've already set up the CNAME records so that http://images/myDomain.com serves my images according to your DNS trick. My MVC's image links are all relative. What I'm not clear on is who/where I map my to MVC's /Content/Images path so that it resolves to my CNAME's path. Do I have an alternative to touching each of my existing links so they point to the subdomain 'images' instead of being relative to the App's root? Seems like IIS should handle this more gracefully.

Comment: You could try IIS rewrite rules to send `www.myDomain.com/Content/Images/*` to `images.myDomain.com/Content/Images/*`.

Comment: Yep...that's what I want to do. I've reviewed the docs for URL Rewrite Module IIS's but can't quite get the syntax.